# How can I get a list of allowed values for a postgres constraint check from php

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4, laravel-5.5, php-7.1

```
CREATE TABLE public.tasks(
id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('tasks_id_seq'::regclass),
title character varying(255) NOT NULL,
status character varying(255) NOT NULL,
type character varying(255) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT tasks_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
CONSTRAINT tasks_status_check CHECK (status::text = ANY (ARRAY['Asignada'::character varying, 'Revision'::character varying, 'Cumplida'::character varying, 'Cancelada'::character varying, 'Diferida'::character varying, 'Retardada'::character varying]::text[])),
CONSTRAINT tasks_type_check CHECK (type::text = ANY (ARRAY['Academico-Docente'::character varying, 'Administrativas'::character varying, 'Creacion intelectual'::character varying, 'Integracion-Social'::character varying, 'Administrativo-Docente'::character varying, 'Produccion'::character varying]::text[])))
WITH ( OIDS=FALSE);
  ALTER TABLE public.tasks
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

Given this table, how can I get the avaliable white-listed values for the constraints tasks_status_check and task_type_check?

In add, I'm trying to do it from Laravel, Laravel creates constraints instead of enums. I've been investigating for a while but couldn't find a solution

I did it in MySql but we are moving to PostgreSql

my code was something like this

```
trait EnumHelper {
   public static function getEnumValues($field){
    $instance = new static;
    $type = DB::select(DB::raw('SHOW COLUMNS FROM '.$instance->getTable().' WHERE Field = "'.$field.'"'))[0]->Type;
    preg_match('/^enum\((.*)\)$/', $type, $matches);
    $values = array();
    foreach(explode(',', $matches[1]) as $value){
        $values[] = trim($value, "'");
    }
    return $values;
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made it, thanks to Klin! His answer was very useful

```
trait EnumHelper {
  public static function getEnumValues($field){
    $instance = new static;
    $types = DB::select("
        select matches[1]
        from pg_constraint,
        regexp_matches(consrc, '''(.+?)''', 'g') matches
        where contype = 'c'
        and conname = '".$instance->getTable()."_".$field."_check'
        and conrelid = 'public.tasks'::regclass;
    ");
    $values = array();
    foreach($types as $type){
        $values[] = $type->matches;
    }
    return $values;
  }
}
```

Works perfectly now.

Answer (score 1):

Query the `consrc` column of the system catalog [`pg_constraint`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/catalog-pg-constraint.html) to get textual representation of a check constraint.

If you are looking for text literals (like in this case) you can use a regular expression and the function [`regexp_matches()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html#functions-posix-regexp), example:

```
select conname, array_agg(matches[1]) as "white list"
from pg_constraint,
regexp_matches(consrc, '''(.+?)''', 'g') matches
where contype = 'c'
and conrelid = 'public.tasks'::regclass
group by 1;

      conname       |                                                   white list                                                    
--------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 tasks_type_check   | {Academico-Docente,Administrativas,"Creacion intelectual",Integracion-Social,Administrativo-Docente,Produccion}
 tasks_status_check | {Asignada,Revision,Cumplida,Cancelada,Diferida,Retardada}
(2 rows)
```